# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'propName' of null

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a rest api project and i want to add UI with react to my project but i have an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'schoolName' of null
```

i have 2 entities my rest api project and 1 foreign key.

My Compenent Methods:

my constructor :

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {id:'',firstName:'',lastName:'',email:'',school:''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

componentDidmount:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/student/getStudent/'+this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(response=>{
            return response.json();
        }).then(result=>{
            console.log(result);
            this.setState({
                id:result.id,
                firstName:result.firstName,
                lastName:result.lastName,
                email:result.email,
                schoolName:result.school.schoolName
            });
    });
}
```

handleChange and handleSubmit methods which i use my render function:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const state = this.state
    state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
}

handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/student/updateStudent/'+this.props.match.params.id,{
        method:'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id:this.state.id,
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            email:this.state.email,
            schoolName:this.state.school.schoolName

        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    }).then(response=>{
        if(response.status===200){
            alert("Student update successfully.");
        }
    });
}
```

a part of render function:

```
<p>
                        <label>School Name :</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="schoolName" value={this.state.schoolName} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="School Name"></input>
                    </p>
```

i try to click submit button and gave me error what i mentioned. Actually i don't know the problem. Please can you help me?

Comment: You set the value to `this.state.schoolName` but try to send `this.state.school.schoolName`.

Comment: You should not mutate the state object like this `handleChange(event) {
    const state = this.state
    state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
}`. You could provide only the state part to be updated `handleChange(e){this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})}`

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have schoolName there:

```
this.setState({
                id:result.id,
                firstName:result.firstName,
                lastName:result.lastName,
                email:result.email,
                schoolName:result.school.schoolName
            });
```

Just change it to:

```
this.setState({
                id:result.id,
                firstName:result.firstName,
                lastName:result.lastName,
                email:result.email,
                school:result.school.schoolName
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in your `handleSubmit` function.

Just change this,

```
JSON.stringify({
   id:this.state.id,
   firstName: this.state.firstName,
   lastName: this.state.lastName,
   email:this.state.email,
   schoolName:this.state.school.schoolName  // error because this.state.school is null and it is wrong also because you have data in  this.state.schoolName
})
```

to this,

```
JSON.stringify({
    id:this.state.id,
    firstName: this.state.firstName,
    lastName: this.state.lastName,
    email:this.state.email,
    schoolName:this.state.schoolName  
})
```

**Note:** Also make sure in `componentDidMount`,

```
this.setState({
     id:result.id,
     firstName:result.firstName,
     lastName:result.lastName,
     email:result.email,
     schoolName:result.school.schoolName // this is not a type, make sure you have schoolName under result.school
});
```

Don't set state like this,

```
handleChange(event) {
    const state = this.state
    state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
}
```

you should do this,

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-i1s1v?fontsize=14)

Comment: it's not working. Same error again. I tihnk my i describe my problem very bad. My state is true?

Comment: Not a line i try to click submit button inside my render function.

Comment: Yes. but when you get error it will come up with line number also.

Comment: yes. Error get a line my students list component which i listed my students like this:`<td>{item.school.schoolName}</td>`

Comment: Are you getting schoolName in input after your page loads?

Comment: You wrote `console.log(result);` in `componentDidMount`, paste the output here.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'schoolName' of null` and this:`TypeError: Cannot read property 'schoolName' of null`

Comment: Yes i did. after i gave this error. i go and look my database, the student's school id which i try to update is null! i think because of this i can not list my students after click this button. I guess this button change my student's school id to null. But why i don't know

Comment: You wrote console.log(result); in componentDidMount, paste the output here.

Comment: `Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.` and same error i comment in my last message

Comment: This is because you missed to write `value` attribute in one of the input.

Comment: Just check Demo I have provided and see how the data is communicated.

Comment: thanks will check it but i think my state should like this: `this.state = {id:'',firstName:'',lastName:'',email:'',school:{
            schoolId:this.props.match.params.id, schoolName:''
            }};`   but its not working again

Comment: Why you need complex state? You can make it simple as I shown. Are you going to use `schoolId`? If not then don't store it, if yes then you can use `this.props.match.params.id` directly so again to use to store in state.

Comment: Make a runnable exampe here - https://codesandbox.io/s/l4w3o6my59, so that I can help more.

Comment: i add but not correctly. i think  perhaps you can understand. I am new react is like horror movie for me  now:(